# lambda expression using scope variables - is safe?

Tags: c++

When f is called, a is already "destructed". Is it safe to use it this way? How does it work?

```
std::function<void()> f;
{
  int a = some_calc();
  f = [=] { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
}
f();
```

Comment: It's fine since `a` is captured by copy. You'll have trouble if capture by-reference, which leads to UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is *conceptually* what is going on:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

int some_calc() {
    // ...
    return 42;
}

int main() {
  std::function<void()> f;
  {
    int a = some_calc();
    class Lambda {
     private:
      int a;

     public:
      Lambda(int const& _a) : a{_a} {}
      void operator()() const { std::cout << a << std::endl; }
    };
    f = Lambda{a};
  }
  f();
}
```

Comment: how about a cppinsights link?
https://cppinsights.io/s/6b507656

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to use it this way?

Yes

> How does it work?

The closure object created by that lambda expression has `int a` as a data member, copy-initialised from the `a` in that scope.